# How to send push notifications to a specific user through Parse?

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, push-notification

I have already set up push notifications through Parse and Apple, and I can't seem to find a straight forward way to send push notifications to another user.

For my case, I want to send a user a notification when a user sends a friend request to them. here is the code I am using to save to request to the server:

```
 //get current user
 PFQuery *query2 = [PFUser query];
    [query2 whereKey:@"username" equalTo:pendingFriendName];
    PFUser *userTo = (PFUser *)[query2 getFirstObject];


    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Follow"];
    [query whereKey:@"from" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

    // execute the query
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

                PFObject *follow = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Follow"];
                [follow setObject:[PFUser currentUser]  forKey:@"from"];
                [follow setObject:userTo forKey:@"to"];
                [follow saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

                    if(succeeded)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"success!");
                        [friendAddedLabel setText:@"Friend Added!"];

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSLog(@"error");
                    }
                }];

            }
          }];
```

In addition, is there a way to send a direct reference of the user who sent the request to the user who received the friend request so that it can quickly have the information accessible when the user taps the notifcation instead of going through another query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to store the current user into Installation class then send push notification using PFInstallation Query and PFPush.

```
//save the user into installtion class.
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
if ([PFUser currentUser].objectId)
{
       currentInstallation[@"user"] = [PFUser currentUser];
       currentInstallation.channels = @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"user_%@",[PFUser currentUser].objectId]];
        NSLog(@"Saving Installation channel = %@",currentInstallation.channels);
        [currentInstallation saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) 
           {
                 NSLog(@"Current installation updated: Error: %@",error);
           }];
}

//Then send push notification to particular user.
PFQuery *queryInstallation = [PFInstallation query];
[queryInstallation whereKey:@"user" equalTo:user];

PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setQuery:queryInstallation];
NSDictionary * dic = @{@"alert" : text,@"badge" : @"Increment" , @"sender" : [PFUser currentUser].objectId ,@"MediaId" : mediaObject.objectId};
[push setData:dic];

[push sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
 {
     if (error != nil && !succeeded)
     {
         NSLog(@"SendPushNotification send error.");
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"SendPushNotification send success.");
     }
 }];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! However, i have just read that there is a security flaw with trying to send a push notification from one user to another, and Parse recommends using Cloud Code to do this. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: no i don't know send notification using cloud code.